# counting to 2 different values with main method and public static final int

Tags: java, loops, int, final

I'm currently running trough "practice it" problems and I'm stuck at this one:
"Suppose that you are trying to write a program that produces the following output using loops. The program below is an attempt at a solution, but it contains at least four major errors. Identify and fix them all.
1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 
1 3 5 7 9 11 "

```
public class BadNews {
    public static final int MAX_ODD = 21;

    public static void writeOdds() {
        // print each odd number
        for (int count = 1; count <= (MAX_ODD - 2); count++) {
            System.out.print(count + " ");
            count = count + 2;
        }

        // print the last odd number
        System.out.print(count + 2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write all odds up to 21
        writeOdds();

        // now, write all odds up to 11
        MAX_ODD = 11;
        writeOdds();
    }
}
```

I've changed code into:

```
public class BadNews {
    public static final int MAX_ODD = 21;

    public static void writeOdds() {
        // print each odd number
        for (int count = 1; count <= (MAX_ODD); count++) {
            System.out.print(count + " ");
            count = count +1; //tried to chacge count++ into count + 2 but it was a miss
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write all odds up to 21
        writeOdds();

        // now, write all odds up to 11
        MAX_ODD = 11;
        writeOdds();
    }
}
```

I thought the last problem was that final int MAX_ODD should be moved into main and changed into "normal" variable (int MAX_ODD) but it ended with problem fail and comment "Your solution must have a class constant. A constant must be declared as 'public static final' outside of any methods in your class."
Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I tested your own code and you just have to delete the "final" from MAX_ODD. Then it runs as you expect it to, and prints what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Code will provide you the expected output.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    writeOdds(21);
    writeOdds(11);
}

public static void writeOdds(int n) {
    // print each odd number
    for (int count = 1; count <= (n); count++) {
        System.out.print(count + " ");
        count = count +1; //tried to chacge count++ into count + 2 but it was a miss
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A property that is declared as final cannot have its value changed after its initial value is set. This initial value is final. The variable must remain at class level, outside of any method so that each method may access it.
Therefore, simply delete the word final.